Fleet IDE backgrounds

I'm using fleet IDE with color theme I found online but my problem is that whenever it sees SQL code it marks it with this ugly color
and when I hover (put the cursor) over a variable or word that is already in the code it highlights it with the light blue color. Does anyone know how to get rid of these backgrounds?


when I hover (put the cursor) over a variable or word that is already in the code it highlights it with the light blue color.

See the bgColor for the identifier.underCaret color key, e.g. for a Dark Fleet theme it has these settings:
"identifier.underCaret": {
    "bgColor": "Gray 50",
    "stripeColor": "#27706C",
    "layer": 200
},

